# Non-directed graph algorithm to find lowest cost path

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, shortest-path

I know a few algorithms that are able to find the lowest cost path for directed graph (just as Dijkstra and Floyd).
Is there any algorithm that works for non-directed graphs?

My problem is: I need to find the lowest cost path from a to b passing through all vertexes (undirected graph).

Comment: This is the Traveling Salesman Problem, which is NP-Complete. What is the size of your graph?

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is: I need to find the lowest cost path from a to b passing
>   through all vertexes (non-oriented graph)

This is the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so there is no known efficient solution to it.

However, if the graph is fairly small, there are some techniques to solve it optimally (in exponential time), like [Dynamic Programming](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~mjserna/docencia/algofib/P07/dynprog.pdf).

In general, changing an undirected graph to a directed one is fairly easy and is done by changing an undirected edge `{u,v}` to two directed edges `(u,v)` and `(v,u)`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have nonnegative edge values, you could consider every edge in an undirected graph as two edges in a directed graph, one pointed to and from connected vertices. Then you could use one of many algorithms including the ones you listed.